# Unable to upgrade to SparkPost 1.4 - Parse Error

Tags: wordpress, email, sparkpost

I get an error when upgrading to SparkPost 1.4 - Have raised an issue on the project but hoping someone can advise how to apply a patch locally to get it working:

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost/-/issues/106

WordPress: 5.9.2

CiviCRM Version: 5.48.1

PHP Version: 4.74.1

Attempting to install SparkPost 1.4 gets the below critical error in WordPress:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/CRM/Sparkpost/Upgrader.php on line 107
```

When viewing line 106 of com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/CRM/Sparkpost/Upgrader.php it looks like there is a missing close brackets. The code is:

```
if (!self::canbeStored($key, $cryptoRegistry) {
```

I tried to change this to:

```
if (!self::canbeStored($key, $cryptoRegistry)) {
```

I now get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions::createExtendedInfo() must be an instance of CRM_Extension_Info, null given, called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php on line 74 and defined in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php:332 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(74): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions::createExtendedInfo(NULL) #1 /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(668): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->preProcess() #62 /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(76): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm() #3 /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), 'display') #4 / in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php on line 332
```

Suggestions welcome on how to fix this!

Comment: Note the updates on the issue ticket.